# How to compile tesseract with visual studio 2015?

Tags: tesseract

I would have imagined that there must be a good tutorial for this, but I could not find any, at least that helps me. I want to use tesseract inside of my programme(so called as a library I think).

So.. Tesseract is only in source, I need to compile it right? I have searched for a handful of websites that asks me to download three or four programmes, but I think I found something more useful.
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling

> 3.04.01
>
> If you have Visual Studio 2015, checkout the repository at Leptonica 1.73 for Visual Studio 2015 which has the solution for Tesseract also and click on build_tesseract.bat. After that you still need to download the language packs.
> I have downloaded VS2015_Tesseract-master.zip, running build_tesseract.bat doesn't do anything visual.

I suppose I need to import tesseract as a project in visual studio? I am quite confused with something called Leptonica and all that. Any detailed help(best if step by step) would be much appreciated.